# Bluetooth connection close itself right after start

Tags: linux, bluetooth, connection, fedora

my problem is the connection with a Bluetooth device. I have a Netbook with an integrated bluetooth device. I want to connect my netbook with an OBD-II interface and write a software to read out the stats of my car. To test the connection, I started by adding the OBD device via the bluetooth menu. The manager connects to the interface and it wants me to wait while the configurations are taking place. This state lasts "forever". After 60-Minutes of waiting, I closed the window. However, the device is shown in the list of available devices. Because I'm not able to switch the button to initiate the connection, I thought about using minicom (the OBD-II interface uses SPP for communicating).

As far as I did understand, I need an initiated connection with a bluetooth device and with it a virtual serial port to connect to with minicom. After reading some postings, I found out that the hcitool should be able to create the bluetooth session. With this I was able to connect to the device and the "connected" button turned on. Unfortunately it switches back after 2 secs.

- `hcitool scan` is able to find the device
- `hcitool cc 00:11:22:33:44:55` is able to connect for the already mentioned 2 secs
- `hcitool con` list the connection if it's called within 2 sec after initiating

I also tried to connect via a Windows PC using putty. Windows connected with the device without a problem and after that, I was able to send requests and get the appropriate answers. So it seems like the interface is working correctly.

I'm using Fedora 17 with gnome3. If you need any output or more information, please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: does noone have any idea, what the reason may be?

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).